# Mapstruct case insensitive mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct, object-object-mapping

is there a way in mapstruct to ignore the case of the fields when mapping. let say i want to map following two classes

```
public class Customer {

    private String ID;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        this.ID = iD;
    }
}


public class CustomerDetails {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

MapStruct is not automatically mapping the fields because getter methods names that doesn't match. Is there a way to configure MapStruct to ignore the case of the fields and map them automatically

Comment: Why isn't the names of the attributes following Java's standard naming convention?

Comment: some of the classes are generated from XSD's (in which some of the fields are acronyms)

Answer (score 4):

A custom `AccessorNamingStrategy` can be implemented that would lowercase the element name and thus making it case insensitive.

e.g.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        return super.getPropertyName( getterOrSetterMethod ).toLowerCase( Locale.ROOT );
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementName(ExecutableElement adderMethod) {
        return super.getElementName( adderMethod ).toLowerCase( Locale.ROOT );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip! I'll add a couple of links.
Docs reference about custom AccessorNamingStrategy: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/index.html#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy
Example project on MapStruct repo: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-spi-accessor-naming

Comment: @GiovanniP. thanks for the links. Is there a way to apply custom AccessorNamingStrategy only for some classes/packages? a way to apply custom AccessorNamingStrategy without extracting it into separate jar (i.e. in the context of Spring Boot app)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can configure mapstruct to map case insensitive but you always can define what should be mapped like this:

```java
@Mapping(source = "ID", target = "id")
CustomerDetails toCustomerDetails(Customer customer);
```

Comment: currently we are doing this but the problem is we have a hundreds of fields we need to map between xml and json classes. Trying to find if there is a easier way of doing it and also want to make sure we don't miss any elements

Comment: TS is searching for "map them automatically" way, and this is just explicit mapping for single field