# Mapstruct: Apply AccessorNamingStrategy To a Single Mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043926) describes how to implement a custom accessor naming  strategy in Mapstruct. In [this example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-spi-accessor-naming/spi-impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/services), the naming strategy is presumably applied to all mappers in the app.

Is there a way to only configure 1 mapper to use a custom naming strategy, and keep it default in all remaining mappers?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible if you restrict it to using it for one Mapper. However it does not make sense to restrict it based on a Mapper, what if you want to map from an Immutable data structure to a java bean data structure. Usually the package can be used to identify if you want to use strategy A or strategy B for this class.

You can write your own custom naming strategy that switches between these strategies depending on which package/class the methods are in.

See below for an example of switching between a custom strategy and the default strategy:

```java
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {
    private static final String CUSTOM_PACKAGE = "custom"; // custom package name.
    private Elements elementUtils;

    @Override
    public void init(MapStructProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init( processingEnvironment );
        elementUtils = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isGetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        if ( isCustomPackage( method ) ) {
            // handle custom route and return.
        } else { // fallback to default
            return super.isGetterMethod( method );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        if ( isCustomPackage( method ) ) {
            // handle custom route and return.
        } else { // fallback to default
            return super.isSetterMethod( method );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        if ( isCustomPackage( method ) ) {
            // handle custom route and return.
        } else { // fallback to default
            return super.getPropertyName( getterOrSetterMethod );
        }
    }

    private boolean isCustomPackage(ExecutableElement method) {
        return getPackage( method ).contains( "." + CUSTOM_PACKAGE + "." ) // subpackage
            || getPackage( method ).endsWith( "." + CUSTOM_PACKAGE ); // current package
    }

    private String getPackage(ExecutableElement element) {
        return elementUtils.getPackageOf( element ).getQualifiedName().toString();
    }
}
```

for more information also see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2957 (which was created after this question got asked)